# Array for Json Month sum of column

Tags: php, json, web, charts

I am currently creating a json file for my chart, now.I wanted to have an output like

> [{"ts":"September","ph":23},{"ts":"July","ph":13}]

where September ph is equivalent to values: 10,8,2,3 and July ph is equivalent to 10 and 3 from my database.

But the reality is I only got this output only

> [{"ts":"September","ph":23}]

which came from the code below. I wanted to add the july ph added values.

```
$sumsep = 0;
$sumjul = 0;
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {        
      /* Push the results in our array */
        //   $point = array("ts" =>  date('m',strtotime($row['time_stamp'])) ,"ph" =>  $row['ph']);
        $monthNum = date('m',strtotime($row['time_stamp']));
        $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
        $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');

        if(($monthName=="September")){
        $data_points = array();
         $sumsep += $row['ph'];
          $point = array("ts" =>  $monthName,"ph" =>  $sumsep);
        array_push($data_points,$point); 
            }

 }
```

Please!! I need your help!!!

Comment: Don't define your `$data_points` array in the loop, you will overwrite it on every iteration. And why is there a condition in your loop? And the math should probably be done by the database: `SUM() ... GROUP BY ...`

Comment: calculating ph sum for each month, should do some query on db side, and yes define your $data_points outside while loop

Comment: Thanks for the interest I am so much grateful..since I am working in an array, the SUM() on the DB doesn't work it must be $sumsep += $row['ph']; .because i need to sum up the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that. That will create an array entry for each month of your mysql query result and sum it.

```
// Init your data point by month array    
$data_points = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {        
    $monthNum = date('m',strtotime($row['time_stamp']));
    $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
    $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');

    // Check if already a result for this month
    if (array_key_exists($monthName, $data_points)) {
        // Sum you pH
        $data_points[$monthName]->ph += $row['ph'];
    } else {
        // Create first pH entry for month
        $data_points[$monthName] = new stdClass();
        $data_points[$monthName]->ph = $row['ph'];
        $data_points[$monthName]->ts = $monthName;
    }
}
// Extract only result (months name as key not needed)
echo json_encode(array_values($data_points));
```

Comment: Kam thanks for the reply! I really appreciate it.but I guess array_key_exist() does not work for this..

Comment: the output is something like this, 

array(3) { ["July"]=> array(2) { ["ts"]=> string(4) "July" ["ph"]=> int(69) } ["August"]=> array(2) { ["ts"]=> string(6) "August" ["ph"]=> int(752) } ["September"]=> array(2) { ["ts"]=> string(9) "September" ["ph"]=> int(13) } }

Comment: needed to have like this output 

[{"ts":"September","ph":23},{"ts":"July","ph":13}]

Comment: Fixed function name and extraction of data, should work now

Comment: yes, its working thank you..but . it works like this:  array(3){ ["July"]=> array(2) { ["ts"]=> string(4) "July" ["ph"]=> int(69) }. I wanted to show the Month and the sum of ph value only..something like this  [{"ts":"September","ph":23},{"ts":"July","ph":13}]

Comment: ..sorry for that but I didnt ..what should i change to this line??

Comment: :-) thanks for the help!! :) I hope there will be someone out there that can also help..thank you so much for the time..very much appreciated!!

Comment: I fix an other misstake, that really should work now :-p

Comment: :-) ..yes but it only shows blank and no print echo at all

Comment: !!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I just ADDED the echo at the end!! Thank you!! I ought you this whole page a lot!!..you are awesome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152063/discussion-between-kam-and-njhelloworld).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152071/discussion-between-njhelloworld-and-kam).